# Can i set the UIView image to cover like in css?

Tags: xcode, image, uiview, cover

At the moment the UIView is set to scale to fit. Is there any way of setting it to fill the whole element and set it to centre?

Answer (score 0):

There is a content scale mode called aspect fill maybe does what you want.

Comment: For some reason that makes the image appear outside its defined UIimage boundary. Like cover in css, I want the image to stay proportioned but fill the div its in.

Comment: AH HA! the clip subviews was unchecked. Working now! Thanks for bringing me back to the origin though Cram.